# iText watermark detector using UnderContent

Tags: itext, watermark

I am working with iText to try and create a very basic, visual watermark detector.

The first part of the program adds a watermark image to the "UnderContent" of a pdf.

I then want to see if I can detect the watermark image at that location, or check to see if the pdf background contains the watermark.

It would look something like this:

```
public static boolean isWatermarked(PdfReader reader) throws DocumentException, IOException{
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("/Watermark_PDFs/results.pdf"));

    boolean wm = false;

    if(stamper.getUnderContent(1) != null) {
        wm = true;
    }
    stamper.close();
    return wm;
}
```

After reading up on getUnderContent from (http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfStamper.html#getUnderContent%28int%29) I realize getUnderContent is not what I want to use to read the under content of a pdf.

Is there a method that I can use to read the data stored in the under content and then make a decision based on that data?

Thanks

Comment: The content of a PDF page is described either in a single PDF stream or in an array of such streams drawn one after the other. If you ask the `PdfStamper` for an *OverContent`or an *UnderContent*, it essentially adds another stream to that array at the beginning and (for the *OverContent*) another one at the end; other software does it differently, though: I think e.g. PDFBox merges everything into one stream. When later analyzing the PDF it might be difficult to recognize such techniques in general, only on a per-library basis.

Comment: Do you control the process that adds the watermarks? If so, you could "mark" the watermarks, and then look for that mark. If not, your requirement isn't feasible for the reasons explained by @mkl

Comment: I do control the process that adds the watermarks.  Currently it is just a tutorial I found online that uses:
add_watermark = stamp.getUnderContent(i);
add_watermark.addImage(watermark_image);

I am currently looking at an overview of PdfContentByte to see if there are any methods I can use to "mark" or tag my watermarks.  Thoughts?

Comment: Mark or Tag to be recognized by whom? You? Certain collaborating Software?  Anything in the market?

Comment: Adding a mark can be done in different ways: adding marked content operators, adding an extra entry to the Form or Image XObject,...

Comment: Great thanks.  I'll take a look at these options.